# Accessing forms from one website to another, python/django

Tags: python, django, web-services, authentication

I'm trying to make a website that requires users to enter information about themselves. In order to check to see if this information is correct, it needs to enter the information on another website (that has an entire database of these types of users). It will then return the results found. How do I do such a thing? Where do I start? I tried googling but I couldn't even think of what this would be called?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're looking to do as it doesn't make much sense.  But you need to validate data provided by users on your site against data available in another database that isn't accessible to your app.

This means you need to send the data your users are providing to you to the other service that is providing the validation.  Perhaps this other service provides an API to do this, perhaps it just provides a form you can post the data to (with python urllib2).

Without have a lot more information on what you're looking to do I can't even venture to guess whether either of these two things are feasible.

Comment: I think we are talking about the same thing. Let me try to get more detailed. As an example: If a doctor tries to sign up for my website, I want to validate that he is a doctor. So I will take his name, and other information, then place it into a form on a website that has the entire database for doctors. When the submit button is pressed on this website, a list of doctors with that information will show up, and then I want python to return this information. Thank you.

Comment: The correct answer is going to be very specific to the service you are using.  You will need to understand the API that the service you are trying to use provides to the data you need.  You will need to understand python's urllib2 and how to have your webserver request data via this api.  If the service doesn't provide an api you'll need to post data and then parse the html response and realize that most likely the service won't appreciate you scraping their site.